# Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't lock when I close the lid

Tags: ubuntu, power-management, acpi

Here's what I did:
I created a file `/etc/acpi/events/lm_lid` and wrote into it:

```
event=button/lid.*
action=/etc/acpi/lid.sh
```

I created a file `/etc/acpi/lid.sh` and wrote into it:

```
#!/bin/sh 
gnome-screensaver-command --lock
```

The good news are that this script is being executed when I close the lid. The bad news are that it doesn't lock the system.
Any other command I put in the script is executed when I close the lid except the lock itself. When I run the script manually from command line the system locks.

What did I miss?

Comment: I think your problem might be that that script is executed outside the X session you want to lock (and probably as another user) .You probably need gnome (I assume that you wanting to run gnome-screensaver is an indication you use gnome) to help you.

Comment: @JothamB Have you solved the problem?

Comment: I moved from Ubuntu 18.04 to Mint. Solved this problem and more. Much better distro.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Debian and faced similar problem,
first, i wont recommend script because it doesn't work in lock screen.

if you are using gnome install gnome-tweaks and it has a option.

alternatively edit the /etc/systemd/logind.conf, just uncomment the HandleLidSwitch=suspend line.

this worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. I can suspend the system but I want to lock it.

Comment: @JothamB There's a setting in Gnome settings under privacy, screen lock. Click on it and set the lock screen after blank for to the option screen turns off.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading **gnome-tweaks** and there should be an option about locking when closing the lid.

To download gnome -tweaks do:
`sudo apt install gnome-tweaks-tool`

You can also use this for tweaking things like right clicking and left clicking.

Comment: It only has an option to suspend. I want to lock without suspending.